# Como recorrer un array JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Necesito Recorrer un array JSON en PHP
URL de Consulta: [http://](http://servperu.ml/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) es una opción , para luego haciendo uso de la función [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) lo decodificamos. Luego ya es más sencillo acceder a los valores orientado a Objetos.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://servperu.ml/search/?dni=00000100');
$obj = json_decode($json);

$error = $obj->coError;
$fecha_caducidad = $obj->feCaducidad;
$tramites = $obj->listaTramites;
echo "Co Error : " . $error . "<br>";

if($error==="0000"){
  echo "Fecha Caducidad : " . $fecha_caducidad . "<br>";
  echo "Cantidad de Trámites : " . count($tramites) . "<br>";

  foreach ($tramites as$value) {
    echo "Número de Trámite  : " .$value->nomTramite . "<br>";
    echo "TI Trámite  : " .$value->tiTramite . "<br>";
    echo "Fecha de Trámite  : " .$value->feTramite . "<br>";
    echo "Sub Tipo de Trámite  : " .$value->subTipoTramite . "<br>";
  }
}
```